# Objective-C - How to test the values of UIPopoverArrowDirection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

when I call the method

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view 
permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections 
animated:(BOOL)animated
```

of UIPopoverController, I pass UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown as arguments for the permittedArrowDirections parameter.

my question is simple :

How can I test the presence of UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown in arrowDirections ?

```
if (arrowDirections == UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown)
    NSLog(@"arrowDirections contains UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown");
```

doesn't work.

Comment: why would you test this? what is possibleDirections?

Comment: I'm building a custom view and I reuse UIPopoverArrowDirection so I need to test which directions are permitted. possibleDirections is arrowDirections in my example sorry. I'm gonna rename it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (arrowDirections & UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown == UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown) {
    NSLog(@"arrowDirections contains UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown");
}
```

Comment: It works. Can you explain the meaning of the "&" in this context please ?

Comment: `&` is the binary AND operator. By ANDing the two values, you basically extract the bits of `UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown` from all the bits set in `arrowDirections`. The resulting value is equal to `UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown` if its bit are set in `arrowDirections` and otherwise not. It's sort of the inverse of using the binary OR (`|`) that you use to add a new value to a bit field.

Comment: @OleBegemann: Any idea why this (arrowDirections == UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown) does nor work?

Comment: Because arrowDirections works like a bit field. You wrote yourself that you are assigning `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown` to the variable. Clearly, `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown != UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown`.

Comment: `(arrowDirections & UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown) != 0` is probably more standard way to say the same, without repeating the constant